# haskell parse error in pattern for n+k pattern

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, ghci

I have started working my way through Erik Meijer's [13-part lectures](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3642) (and Graham Hutton's [slides](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html#slides)) to learn Haskell.

On the slides for Chapter 4, on page 13, it introduces the pattern-matching syntax for n+k patterns.  In particular, it says:

> As in mathematics, functions on integers can be defined using n+k
>   patterns, where n is an integer variable and k>0 is an integer
>   constant.

```
pred :: Int -> Int
pred (n+1) = n
```

When I tried this on my own in the REPL I get an error message:

```
*Main> let mypred (n+1) = n

<interactive>:65:13: Parse error in pattern: n + 1
```

Similarly, if I try it in a `*.hs` file

```
mypred :: Int -> Int
mypred (n+1) = n
```

The compiler gives a similar complaint:

```
/Users/pohl/Code/praxis-haskell/helloworld.hs:14:9:
    Parse error in pattern: n + 1
```

Am I not understanding how n+k patterns are intended to be used?

Comment: the link for slides is broken, can you share new link?

Comment: Were you getting a 404? It still works for me.

http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to enable it by `-XNPlusKPatterns`.

```
ghci -XNPlusKPatterns
Prelude> let mypred (n+1) = n
Prelude> mypred 2
1
```

Similarly in a `hs` file.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-}

mypred :: Int -> Int
mypred (n+1) = n
```

After loading in ghci

```
*Main> mypred 2
1
```

Comment: Well, that did the trick. (Thank you!) Is this an experimental feature?  Does anybody know why this needs to be enabled in this way?

Comment: @pohl I think it was removed and now available only as extension. http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RemoveNPlusK

Comment: Cool.  That's a tiny glimpse into the kind of thinking that has brought about such an elegant language.  So refreshing to see something removed!

Comment: @pohl: Yes! "In many cases it is not filling the helium balloon but cutting off the sandbag that gets you aloft." (found http://wadler.blogspot.com/2012_05_01_archive.html)

Answer (score 9):

> Am I not understanding how n+k patterns are intended to be used?

Actually, nowadays `n+k` patterns are considered bad practice. The main reason for this is that the syntax doesn't really look like anything else in Haskell, the `+` part isn't really using the `+` that is in scope, unlike say how the `do` notation works. Also, the [viewpatterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) extension is kind of a generalization that is useful in *many* more settings.

There is more info [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RemoveNPlusK) on why it was removed.