# Haskell syntax: what does drop (n+1) [] = [] mean?

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming

What does `(n+1)` mean? I understand both are recursive Haskell functions and are using pattern matching.

I don't understand how it will pattern match `factorial (n+1)` as well as the `(n+1)` on the RHS of `factorial =`.

And with the `drop` function why is it `drop 0 xs = xs`? And what about `drop (n+1) [] = []`?

```
--Example 1
factorial 0 = 1
factorial (n+1) = (n+1) * factorial n

--Example 2
drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop 0 xs = xs
drop (n+1) [] = []
drop (n+1) (_:xs) = drop n xs
```

By the way I get errors when compiling.

- Code failed to compile
- Parse error in pattern: n + 1

Update:
Thanks for pointing me to the correct terminology. I found this [n+k patterns](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Things_to_avoid#n.2Bk_patterns).
Since n+k patterns have been removed since 2010 I also found this question on [how to enable this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250717/haskell-parse-error-in-pattern-for-nk-pattern).

Comment: Now which answer should I accept? Both are great!

Comment: Whichever helped you most, or don't accept one if you can't decide. Neither sepp2k nor I will weep about the 15 points.

Comment: Both... X_X 50% vs 50%. Damn!

Comment: @DanielFischer, well if there is a correct answer, I guess it is good stackoverflow etiquette to accept one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a so called `n+k` pattern. The pattern `(n+1)` matches any positive integer and gives `n` the value of that integer minus one. So if you call `drop 1 xs` the value of `n` will be 0.

> why is it `drop 0 xs = xs`

Because if you remove 0 elements from a list, you end up with the same list.

> And what about `drop (n+1) [] = []`?

That says that if you remove any amount of items from the empty list, you end up with a list that's still empty. Other than failing with an error message, that's really the only sensible thing you can do in that case.

Comment: "It matches any positive integer and gives n the value of that integer minus one." now I am totally totally confused...!!!

Comment: By "minus one" did you really mean "minus k"?

Comment: @Jeff If you call `drop 1 xs` then `n` is 0 because `0+1` is `1`, so `drop 1 xs` matches `drop (0+1) xs`, which matches `drop (n+1) xs` for `n=0`.

Comment: What about (n+2)? Sorry still confused :_)

Comment: @Jeff Sorry, yes, I was specifically about `n+1` in that sentence. Generally an `n+k` pattern matches a number greater than or equal to `k` and gives `n` the value of that integer minus `k`.

Comment: @Jeff No, there never were `n-k` patterns. Ugh, I just imagined there were, and sombody mixed `n+k` and `n-k` patterns.

Comment: is k then strictly positive? (can one use `n+(-1)`?)

Answer (score 7):

These are `NPlusKPatterns`, which were removed from the language in 2010, and are now only available with the mentioned language extension.

An `n + k`-pattern

```
drop (n+1) [] = []
```

binds `n` to the argument value minus one, provided that the argument value is `>= 1`. The pattern does not match arguments `<= 0`.

So if

```
drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop 0 xs = xs
drop (n+1) [] = []
drop (n+1) (_:xs) = drop n xs
```

is called with a negative `Int` argument, like

```
drop (-2) "foo"
```

no pattern matches, and you get an exception.

Generally, if you define (for a stupid example)

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo (n+5) = 3*n
foo (n+2) = n
foo (n+1) = 2*n
```

if you call `foo 7`, the first pattern matches and `n` will be bound to `2`, so `foo 7 = 6`. If you call `foo 3`, the first pattern doesn't match (`3-5 = -2 < 0`), but the second does, and that binds `n` to `3-2 = 1`, hence `foo 3 = 1`. If you call `foo 1`, neither of the first two patterns matches, but the last does, and then `n` is bound to `1 - 1 = 0`, so `foo 1 = 0`. Calling `foo` with an argument `< 1` raises an exception.

> And with drop function why is it `drop 0 xs = xs`? And what about `drop (n+1) [] = []`?

Well, `drop 0` drops 0 elements from the front of the list, so it doesn't change the list argument at all. And you can't drop elements from an empty list, so `drop (n+1) [] = []` is the only thing you can do except raising an error.

Comment: Confused and so you are saying I don't need to learn this pattern as a newbie Haskeller?

Comment: More or less. If the book/tutorial you learn from uses them (extensively), you need to (and will) learn them. But they have been removed from the language with a reason, and you won't see many `n+k`-patterns in production code.

Comment: Confused = this is partly why they removed it.

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided uses feature called `NPlusKPatterns` that is no longer part of standard haskell (Not in the `haskell2010` standard), but it is possible to "import" it by putting the line
`{-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-}` at the top of the source file.

Lets look at an example of how to use it:

```
myFunction 0 = 0
myFunction (n+1) = n
```

This function is somewhat silly. If the input is `0` then the result is `0`. For a positive input number `m` the result is `m - 1`, or said differently, for a positive input number `n+1` the result is `n`. The function is undefined for negative numbers since the `(n+1)` pattern does not match negative numbers.

Now lets say I changed my function to

```
myFunction 0 = 0
myFunction (n+1) = (n+1)
```

Now the left side does some magic. It declares a variable `n` which is one minus the input. The right side on the other hand, adds back one to it with the `(+)` operator.

As for your questions about the `drop` function. `drop 0 xs = xs` means that dropping `0` elements from a list doesn't change the list. `drop (n+1) [] = []` is simply that dropping any positive number of elements from an empty list is the empty list.

The definition of `drop` from the `haskell2010` report is:

```
drop n xs     | n <= 0 =  xs
drop _ []              =  []
drop n (_:xs)          =  drop (n-1) xs
```

which behaves somewhat differently since it is defined for negative numbers.